# ROSserial can't find clock_gettime

Tags: ros, linux, compile, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have been trying to compile the rosserial example "HelloROS" for embedded linux, but to no avail.

There are undefined references to "clock_gettime" however i have found the prototypes in time.h - here they are defined as extern's.

> extern int clock_gettime (clockid_t __clock_id, struct timespec *__tp) __THROW;

I believe the time library is linking, it has been included in EmbeddedLinuxHardware.h.

Do I have to write the clock_gettime function myself?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101331/rosserial-can%27t-find-clock_gettime/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on your setup, `clock_gettime` may be in libc, or it may be in librt.

Try adding `-lrt` as a link flag and see if that clears things up.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2